# how to access eureka by dns name in kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes

I am deploy eureka in kubernetes(v1.15.2) cluster.Now I want to using my app pod register to eureka by domain name,first I try this way:

```
http://eureka-0.eureka.dabai-fat.svc.cluster.local:8761
```

It not works.I am login my app pod using this command:

```
/opt/k8s/bin/kubectl exec -ti soa-room-service-6c4448dfb6-grhtb -n dabai-fat /bin/sh
```

and using curl command to access cluster's eureka this way:

```
  / # curl http://eureka-0.eureka.dabai-fat.svc.cluster.local:8761
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: eureka-0.eureka.dabai-fat.svc.cluster.local
```

but using this way works:

```
/ # curl http://172.30.224.17:8761
{"timestamp":"2020-02-03T17:10:23.037+0000","status":401,"error":"Unauthorized","message":"Unauthorized","path":"/"}
```

But I think the domain or dns way is better because the ip could floating in the future. So what is the right way to register to eureka using dns? My coredns in the namespace `kube-sytem`,and my eureka service and app pod in `dabai-fat` namespace. By the way,this is my eureka service info in kubernetes:

[image]

Comment: Is your coredns service reachable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have service with name `eureka-0.eureka` in `dabai-fat` namespace ? You can check it via `kubectl get svc -n dabai-fat`.

Comment: only have name eureka,I change the name should make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Check the service and change the url to http://eureka.dabai-fat.svc.cluster.local:8761, It works.

```
/ # curl http://eureka.dabai-fat.svc.cluster.local:8761
{"timestamp":"2020-02-03T17:29:08.045+0000","status":401,"error":"Unauthorized","message":"Unauthorized","path":"/"}
```

this is service check command output:

```
[root@ops001 ~]# kubectl get svc -n dabai-fat
NAME                       TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)             AGE
eureka                     ClusterIP   None             <none>        8761/TCP,8081/TCP   2d
soa-auth-service           ClusterIP   10.254.84.39     <none>        11013/TCP           2d8h
```